# SIP Subscribe Receives 486 BUSY HERE

Tags: sip, jain-sip

I am trying to SUBSCRIBE to a watcher list and the server frequently responds with 486 BUSY HERE. However, the RFCs describe 486 as a possible response for an INVITE, which make more sense for this response.
 At other times, the server does respond correctly - with a 200 OK, followed by a NOTIFY request.
*I am working with an ALU IMS core.*
Has anyone seen this issue?

My SUBSCRIBE Request:

```
SUBSCRIBE sip:yyyyyyyyyyy@example.com;transport=TCP SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 81fcd7229c882f230c726e21f16aadc9@10.0.2.15
CSeq: 4 SUBSCRIBE
From: "XXXX" <sip:yyyyyyyyyyy@example.com>;tag=92521573
To: <sip:yyyyyyyyyyy@example.com>
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.0.2.15:5060;branch=z9hG4bK68630e2ec7c21d2e991854010b7f64543332
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:yyyyyyyyyyy@10.0.2.15:5060;transport=TCP>;+g.oma.sip-im;expires=3600
User-Agent: My Android Client/OMA1.0
Require: pref
Supported: replaces,100rel,eventlist,timer
Event: presence.winfo
Accept: application/watcherinfo+xml
Route: <sip:yyyyyyyyyyy@z.z.z.z:5060;transport=TCP;lr>
Expires: 3600
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to remember with SIP response codes is there are no hard and fast rules about which specific response code should be used in all situations. Invariably a real World error condition on a SIP server or UAS does not fall neatly into the definition of one of the SIP failure response codes so the closest one is used and the status message may be customised and/or a Warning header added.

The 486 response is a little bit unusual for a SUBSCRIBE request but it could easily make sense. For example if the SIP notification server maintaining the subscriptions has a limit on how many active subscriptions it will maintain or if it's overloaded and doesn't want to process subscription requests for a while.

I'd have a closer look at the 486 response and see if there is a Warning or any other informational type header. Also check whether the response is coming from the intermediate proxy you are using or the end server.

Comment: I'm performing two SUBSCRIBEs: One for the buddy list and one for the watchers list. When it fails, it only fails for the watchers list, and never for the buddy list. This happens even if I reverse the order of these two SUBSCRIBEs.

Comment: Do you always get a failure when subscribing to the watchers list? Are you able to check the failure responses you are getting for more info like Warning headers. Apart from that the best way to find out what's going on is to find out from the server why it's rejecting the requests by looking at its logs or whatever other mechanisms its got.

Comment: I've asked ALU for an explanation as well. In the meantime, the response does not include additional headers.

Answer (score 1):

486 is not a response code define in [RFC3265](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3265.txt). You need to trace your server (if possible) to understand why it decided to send such an unexpected error code.

Sorry for not being much help. I have been working with SIP for several years and never heard of a 486 response for a SUBSCRIBE request. When you find out the reason I'd like to know about it too.